# Delete from GridView in ModalpopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopupExtender which is, among other things, populated with a gridview (From a DataTable).

In this GridView I have a deletebutton attached to each row, which is supposed to delete the row. Is it anyway possible to delete the selected row from the datatable, and then update the GridView without closing the ModalPopupExtender?

Here is my GridView:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupDragHandleControlID="divPopupReport"  TargetControlID="btnHidden" PopupControlID="divPopupReport" CancelControlID="btnCloseReport" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upReport">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="divPopupReport" runat="server" style="text-align:left; padding-right:0px; background-color:White; border: 2px solid #87d000; display:none;" >

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="list listExtended" 
                        DataKeyNames="DocumentGuid" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentName" HeaderText="Dokumentname">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="list"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CardName" HeaderText="Reference">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="list"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentDate" HeaderText="Date">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="list"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="list" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="list" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" CssClass="image" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentGuid") %>' ImageUrl="~/delete.gif" Width="16" Height="16" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
</div>    
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And below my RowCommand.

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        DataTable SelectedDataTable = Session["SelectedDataTable"] as DataTable;
        string guid = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
        DataRow[] dr = SelectedDataTable.Select("DocumentGuid = '" + guid + "'");
        SelectedDataTable.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
        Session["SelectedDataTable"] = SelectedDataTable;
        GridView2.DataSource = SelectedDataTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `upReport` panel with `divPopupReport` div (i.e. place `upReport` UpdatePanel into `divPopupReport` div).

Comment: Thanks for the respons. But that's not it - the row is still in the GridView (When I try debugging, the row IS deleted from the DataTable). I added the upReport and ContentTemplate inside the divPopupReport-tag.

Comment: Changed the 'Delete' RowCommand to a onClick-listener insteader which did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap an UpdatePanel around the grid. This should solve the problem.

Another option is to use ajax.
Using Javascript/JQuery to remove the table row manually in combination with a WebMethod:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Another easy solution is to re-show the popup after post back.